# Django project folder structure

Tags: python, django

I am trying to organize my django project structure as:

```
- myproject
  -- manage.py
  -- main_application
  -- third_party
     --- tastypie
```

But when i put tastypie in third_party folder and add it to installed applications with 'third_party.tastypie'  tastypie models.py gives error:

```
from tastypie.utils import now
ImportError: No module named 'tastypie'
```

How can i fix this issue without touching to tastypie models.py code?

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the `tastypie` directory?

Comment: Why do you want to put the Tastypie package inside you project structure ? Also you might need a `__init__.py` file at the root of Tastypie's dir if that's really what you want. (edit : too slow ^^)

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I would highly recommend you to look at virtualenvs in combination with a `requirements.txt` to install your packages :)

Comment: Your tastypie is acting as a folder instead of a Django app. Try shaktimaan's solution. Create an empty __init__.py file in that folder.

in linux you can do:
touch __init__.py

Comment: @Wolph can you give an example on using requirements.txt  ( i am already using virtualenvs )

Comment: Basically it comes down to adding `tastypie` to a `requirements.txt`. If you need to install it on a different machine you can simply do `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're organising your environment wrong. Try using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html). It gives you a nice way to isolate all of your project dependancies, so you can `pip install tastypie` inside a virtualenv, which will put tastypie in the correct location for every app inside that environment to find. I strongly recommend this solution.

On a side note and if you insist on not using virtualenv: you should either add `/path/to/byproject/third_party` to `sys.path` or add an empty `__init__.py` to your `third_party` directory and import it like `from third_party.tastypie.utils import now`